# How to use a Docker image from a Azure DevOps stage?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

**CONTEXT**

I need to build multiple docker images, which requires a specific order. To execute such order, I've created 2 stages, the first one, which is responsible for building all base images, and the second, which need those base images to build specific images.

```
stages:
- stage: base
  displayName: Base Images
  jobs:
  - job: Docker
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
    timeoutInMinutes: 120
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.6'
        architecture: 'x64'
    - script: python build.py
      env:
        DOCKER_PASSWORD: $(DOCKER_PASSWORD)
    strategy:
      matrix:        
        Ubuntu GCC 4.9 x86_64:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "4.9"
        Ubuntu GCC 4.9 x86:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "4.9"
          DOCKER_ARCHS: "x86"
        Ubuntu GCC 5 x86_64:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "5"
        Ubuntu GCC 5 x86:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "5"
          DOCKER_ARCHS: "x86"
        Ubuntu GCC 5.2 x86_64:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "5.2"
        Ubuntu GCC 5.3 x86_64:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "5.3"
        Ubuntu GCC 6 x86_64:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "6"
        Ubuntu GCC 6 x86:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "6"
          DOCKER_ARCHS: "x86"

- stage: specilized
  displayName: Specilized Images
  jobs:
  - job: Docker
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
    timeoutInMinutes: 120
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.6'
        architecture: 'x64'
    - script: python build.py
      env:
        DOCKER_PASSWORD: $(DOCKER_PASSWORD)
    strategy:
      matrix:                
        Jenkins Slave GCC 4.9 x86_64:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "4.9"
          DOCKER_ARCHS: "x86_64"
          DOCKER_DISTRO: "jnlp-slave"
        Jenkins Slave GCC 4.9 x86:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "4.9"
          DOCKER_ARCHS: "x86"
          DOCKER_DISTRO: "jnlp-slave"
        Jenkins Slave GCC 5 x86_64:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "5"
          DOCKER_ARCHS: "x86_64"
          DOCKER_DISTRO: "jnlp-slave"
        Jenkins Slave GCC 5 x86:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "5"
          DOCKER_ARCHS: "x86"
          DOCKER_DISTRO: "jnlp-slave"
        Jenkins Slave GCC 6 x86_64:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "6"
          DOCKER_ARCHS: "x86_64"
          DOCKER_DISTRO: "jnlp-slave"
        Jenkins Slave GCC 6 x86:
          GCC_VERSIONS: "6"
          DOCKER_ARCHS: "x86"
          DOCKER_DISTRO: "jnlp-slave"
```

The script python build.py calls docker client to build a docker image. The first stage provides all base images which should be used by the second stage. Also, all those images should be uploaded, but only when on master branch (condition checked by build.py).

**PROBLEM**

The second stage does not use the images generated from the first stage, it downloads the latest version available on Hub Docker.

**QUESTION**

How could I use those images generated on first stage instead of downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant (well, unless all the stages run on your own build agent).

you could either save it to some registry and pull it on the second stage before doing builds or do everything in one stage (or use private agents).

Comment: Yes, I thought on this option, I think I'll use it. thanks